# Refactoring if statements when changing same value on different conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have been working on refactoring some code and then i make something like this. Main idea is that i have couple Methods which contains implementations and they change referenced string variable **name** in my case.

What i don't like here is situation that in every if statement returning same variable (but with different result).

So my question does someone have better idea for eventually refactoring this? Is there any problem doing this in if statements (from logical, clean code side etc).

All my methods have `ref` keyword (for string variable name). Sorry for confusion!

```
 private string GenerateNameFrom(IRow row)
 {
    string name = string.Empty;

    if (Method1(name,row))
        return name;
    else if (Method2(name,row))
        return name;
    else if (Method3(name,row))
        return name;
    else return "Null";
}
```

Comment: `if (Method1(name) || Method2(name) || Method3(name)) return name`? I can't see `name` *changing* in the context - no **ref** in any `Method` call

Comment: Are you missing the `ref` keyword from your example code? Because you seem to be implying that the methods change the value of `name`.

Comment: The variable name will always have an empty string. as you declare and initialize just before if statement.

Comment: I have ref keyword in every method declaration, sorry!

Comment: @NSKBpro you need to edit your question with those "ref"s, because that difference is important.

Comment: Side note: it seems that you *don't use* `IRow row` at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
private string GenerateNameFrom(IRow row)
{
    var name = "";
    return (Method1(ref name) || Method2(ref name) || Method3(ref name)) ? name : "Null";
}
```

- Using [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) to instantiate the empty string, no need to write `string` twice.
- Using [`||`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator) means that the first method that returns `true` will satisfy the condition and no other method will be executed.
- Using the [`?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) operator for conditional return.

**Note:** As Matthew Watson commented, you are probably missing the `ref` (or `out` keyword - because even though a string is a reference type, it's also immutable, so if you want your methods to effect the content of the `name` argument, you must either send it as `ref` or as `out`, since the only way to change it's value is to assign a new string to it.

(also converted the `String.Empty` to `""`, but that's just personal preference)

Comment: *also converted the `String.Empty` to`""`* well that would generate a stylecop warning and should be other way round ... just fyi :)

Comment: @Rahul you beat me to it. Should definitely be `string.Empty` (also notice that you should always use the type alias where possible, rather than the assembly qualified name)

Comment: @Rahul Well, there was a time when I preferred using `string.Empty` over `""`. Then I made the mistake of find & replace for entire solution, only to realize one second too late I've messed up all my xml files. Never again. Lucky, I'm not working with stylecop and not bound to it's rules.

Answer (score 3):

The variable name will always have an empty string. as you declare and initialize just before if statement

Any how below the short way to get the same result. The Result will be same of the below code and your code:

```
if (Method1(name) || Method2(name) || Method3(name))
{
    return name;
}
else
{ 
    return "Null";
}
```

**Or more specifically using ternary operator**

```
(Method1(name) || Method2(name) || Method3(name)) ? name : "Null";
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't see the implementation of your methods but I'm assuming something like:

```
public bool Method1(ref string name)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        name = "SomeValue";
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You could refactor those methods to return the updated name:

```
public string Method1(name)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return "SomeValue";
    }

    return null;
}
```

And then you could just null coalesce the method calls:

```
private string GenerateNameFrom(IRow row)
{
    string name = string.Empty;
    return Method1(name)
        ?? Method2(name)
        ?? Method3(name)
        ?? "Null";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well all of this `Method1(name)` and `Method2(name)` doing some validation over the input string `name` and returning `bool`. In that case would suggest you to combine all those validation logic inside single method using a `switch` statement probably and use that method instead

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid using `ref` in this case. Instead, you could make the various methods return a tuple `(bool success, string value)` like so:

```
public static (bool success, string value) Method1(string name)
{
    if (name == "test")
        return (true, "changed");

    return (false, null);
}

public static (bool success, string value) Method2(string name)
{
    if (name == "test")
        return (true, "changed");

    return (false, null);
}

public static (bool success, string value) Method3(string name)
{
    if (name == "test")
        return (true, "changed");

    return (false, null);
}
```

Then you can write the calling code like so (it's not shorter, but it avoids `ref`). Whether you like this better is probably a matter of taste...

```
private string GenerateNameFrom(/*IRow row*/)
{
    string name = string.Empty;

    var result = Method1(name);

    if (result.success)
        return result.value;

    result = Method2(name);

    if (result.success)
        return result.value;

    result = Method3(name);

    if (result.success)
        return result.value;

    return null;
}
```

Alternatively, if `null` can be used to indicate "no result" then just do a similar thing but checking the return value for `null`:

```
private string GenerateNameFrom(/*IRow row*/)
{
    string name = string.Empty;

    var result = Method1(name);

    if (result != null)
        return result;

    result = Method2(name);

    if (result != null)
        return result;

    return Method3(name);
}

public static string Method1(string name)
{
    if (name == "test")
        return "changed";

    return null;
}

public static string Method2(string name)
{
    if (name == "test")
        return "changed";

    return null;
}

public static string Method3(string name)
{
    if (name == "test")
        return "changed";

    return null;
}
```